# expected dense_3 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,) Image Classification with Keras (Maleria deases)

Tags: python, keras, model, deep-learning

Im beginner
I have two folder infected & Noninfected (Each contains 13,780 Images)
Im using Sequential Model and resized images to (32x32) with RGB

My model architecture is

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1024, input_shape=(3072,), activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(512, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(len(lb.classes_), activation="softmax"))

INIT_LR = 0.01
EPOCHS = 75

opt = SGD(lr=INIT_LR)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
              metrics=["accuracy"])

H = model.fit(xtrain, ytrain, validation_data=(xtest, ytest),
        epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=32)
```

ERROR:
File "/root/PycharmProjects/testing/exx.py", line 59, in 
    epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=32)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/testing/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 965, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/testing/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1593, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/testing/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1430, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/testing/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 120, in _standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))

**ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)**

Comment: Your `y_train` is probably just a single column (as you have two classes). Change your models last layer to `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')` and use `binary_crossentropy`.

Comment: Please provide `ytrain.shape` output.